Error no applicable method for 'summarise' applied to an object of class "c('SharedData', 'R6')"
Tengo un flexdashboard que captura una consulta de SQL y dibuja un gráfico con un porcentaje calculado con las sumas de unas columnas. Quiero crear un ShareData para filtrar con un filter_slider las fechas. El filtro funciona bién, pero no se me acualiza el gráfico porque no puedo calcular los summariza en un objeto de clase ShareDate.
Al usar el filter_slider, si que la tabla se va actulizando. Pero no sé cómo pasar los datos filtrados al gráfico.
El dataframe tf sí que me permite ejecutar la función summarize, pero el ShareData eq no.
Adjunto código:
---
title: "Panel Control FIV 1"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: column
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)
library(ggforce)
library(crosstalk)
library(DT)
library(shiny)


con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                 Server = "SQL-01",
                 Database = "XXXXX",
                 UID = "XXXXX",
                 PWD = "XXXXX",
                 Port = 2222)


#dbListFields(con, "xxxxx_Vista_R1")

#df <- DBI::dbReadTable(con,"xxxxx_Vista_R1")
df <- dbReadTable(con, "xxxxx_Vista_R_FIV_SM")

```



```{sql connection = con, output.var="Tabla1"}
SELECT tfec, MII, [2pn] as dospn, FechaPuncion
FROM dbo.xxxxx_Vista_R_FIV_SM
```

# Graficos
### % Fecundación FIV Fresco

```{r}

tf <- Tabla1
tf[is.na(tf)] <- 0


tasafn <- summarize(tf, sum(dospn))*100
tasafd <- summarize(tf, sum(MII))
tasafr <- tasafn/tasafd
percentage_done = round(tasafr/100, digits = 2)
l1 <- "MII: "
l2 <- as.character(summarize(tf, sum(MII)))
l3 <- "/ 2PN: "
l4 <- as.character(summarize(tf, sum(dospn)))
lf <- paste(l1,l2,l3,l4)
tasaffivfrescos <- round(percentage_done * 100,0)

gauge(as.numeric(tasaffivfrescos), min = 0, max = 100, symbol = "%", gaugeSectors(success = c(70,100), warning = c(50,69), danger = c(0,49)), label=lf )

```


# Tablas

```{r}
tf$FechaPuncion <- as.Date(tf$FechaPuncion)
eq <- SharedData$new(tf)
```


### Tasa de Fecundación {data-height=350}
```{r}
filter_slider("FechaPuncion","Fecha", eq, width = 300, step= 1, column = ~FechaPuncion, timeFormat="%F")
```

```{r}
eq %>%
  DT::datatable()
```

### 

```{r}
tasafn <- summarize(eq, sum(dospn))*100
tasafd <- summarize(eq, sum(MII))
tasafr <- tasafn/tasafd
percentage_done = round(tasafr/100, digits = 2)

l1 <- "MII: "
l2 <- as.character(summarize(filtered_df, sum(MII)))
l3 <- "/ 2PN: "
l4 <- as.character(summarize(eq, sum(dospn)))
lf <- paste(l1,l2,l3,l4)

tasaffivfrescos <- round(percentage_done * 100,0)

gauge(as.numeric(tasaffivfrescos), min = 0, max = 100, symbol = "%", gaugeSectors(success = c(70,100), warning = c(50,69), danger = c(0,49)), label=lf )
```



```

